# Some pointers for compiling vue components into "normal" webpages

Tags: vue.js, webpack, deployment

Currently I'm deploying my vue-enhanced webpages in a rather ineffective way

```html
    <html>
     <head>...</head>
     <body>...
       <!-- some markup -->

       <div id="app">
         <component-a />
         <component-b />
       </div>

       <script src="vue.js"></script>
       <script type="module">
         import ComponentA from "component-a.js";
         import ComponentB from "component-b.js";

         const app = new Vue({
           el: "#app",
           components: {
             'component-a': ComponentA,
             'component-b': ComponentB
           },
           data: {}
           ...
         });
       </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

What I want to achieve is something like

```html
    <html>
     <head>...</head>
     <body>...
       <!-- some markup -->

       <div id="app">
         <component-a />
         <component-b />
       </div>

       <script src="app.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

with app.js wrapping vue.js and components (perhaps with Babel along the way). Right now I've gone through a lot of examples but they all seem to assume a script-only approach. Naturally I could manually try to combine all the scripts and deploy the result. I've worked with gulp so far, but when it comes to vue gulp doesn't provide any solutions.

I cobbled together a webpack.config.js (partially understanding what it is doing)

```js
const path = require( 'path' );
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = function( env = {} ) {

    if ( env.production ) {
        process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
    }

    return {
        entry: './src/main.js',

        output: {
            path: path.resolve( __dirname, '../../assets' ),
            filename: env.production ? 'js/main.min.js' : 'js/main.js'
        },

        plugins: env.production ? [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin( {
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: '"production"'
                }
            } )
        ] : [
            new VueLoaderPlugin()
        ],

        optimization: {
            minimize: true
        },

        devtool: env.production ? false : '#cheap-module-eval-source-map',

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },

        resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.js', '.vue', '.json' ],
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve( __dirname, '..' )
            }
        }

    };
};
```

with main.js

```js
mport Vue from 'vue';
import MessageToast from './components/message-toast';

Vue.component("message-toast", MessageToast);

new Vue(
    {
        el: "#app",
        mounted () {
            console.log("mounted");
        },
        methods: {
            buttonclick () {
                this.$refs.toast.isActive = true;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

and index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <main id="app">
      <message-toast ref="toast">Hi!</message-toast>
      <button type="button" @click.prevent="buttonclick">Click me!</button>
    </main>
    <script src="resources/assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The application responds with a "mounted" in the console, but the markup of the page is completely removed.

How - if at all - can achieve my intended solution?

Comment: Have you tried [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org)? I think it would save you a lot of trouble, especially in configuring Webpack automatically while also providing config options to tweak.

Comment: Was one of my first tries. Naturally the generated example falls flat when using my "normal" setup, i.e. a http://localhost/vue-generated/public/index.html gives me the html file. My web application generates the frontend templates with PHP, therefore a `yarn serve` doesn't really help my cause. And all the picked options are baked into a yarn.lock file - I can't see anything useful when it comes to "picking options" for my problem.

Comment: Maybe Nuxt.js static generation? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html#Nuxt-js

Comment: The `yarn.lock` file specifies dependencies, not options (unless you actually mean something else). And your templates being generated by PHP doesn't preclude you from using Vue CLI to build them. Vue CLI supports your use case as described. If you continue on your current path, you might find yourself reinventing the build utility of Vue CLI.

Comment: I'm aware what yarn.lock does (similar to composer.lock). I assume that I should not invoke create but instead the answer to my problem lies somewhere in there https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/ Correct?

Comment: Indeed: This looks promising https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component